# How to access scenario context or page inside AfterFeature hook

Tags: c#, specflow, playwright-sharp

I have following BeforeScenario hook in specflow:

```
private readonly ScenarioContext _scenarioContext;
public Hooks(ScenarioContext scenarioContext, ITestOutputHelper testOutput)
{
    _scenarioContext = scenarioContext;
    _testOutput = testOutput;
}

[BeforeScenario]
public async Task TestFixtureSetUp()
{
    SetAttachmentFileName();

    var page = BrowserSession.Page;
    _scenarioContext.ScenarioContainer.RegisterInstanceAs(page);
    _scenarioContext.ScenarioContainer.RegisterInstanceAs(page.Context);
    _scenarioContext.ScenarioContainer.RegisterInstanceAs(page.Context.Browser!);
    _scenarioContext.ScenarioContainer.RegisterInstanceAs(page.PageLocator());
    _scenarioContext.ScenarioContainer.RegisterInstanceAs(_testsConfig);
    _scenarioContext.ScenarioContainer.RegisterInstanceAs(_configuration);

    await BrowserSession.StartChunkTracing(_scenarioContext.ScenarioInfo.Title);
}
```

Now I want to create AfterFeature hook to cleanup some data after feature, but I don't know how to access created pages or scenario Context inside AfterFeature method.

Comment: Do you have an `[AfterScenario]`?

Comment: You can specify a `FeatureContainer` parameter to the `[AfterFeature]` hook. Does that object get you what you want? The scenario isn't available at that point.

Answer (score 0):

The `[AfterScenario]` hook does not have access to any of the scenario-related objects, but it does have access to the object container (i.e., the IOC container or DI container).

Based on your code snippet, the FeatureContext is all you need:

```
[AfterFeature]
public static void AfterFeature(FeatureContext feature)
{
    var page = feature.FeatureContainer.Resolve<YourPageClassHere>();
//                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <-- IObjectContainer
}
```

Anything you need that is scenario-specific must go in an `[AfterScenario]` hook:

```
[AfterScenario]
public void AfterScenario()
{
    // Just me making a big assumption here
    await BrowserSession.StopChunkTracing(_scenarioContext.ScenarioInfo.Title);
}
```

Comment: unfortunatelly feature.FeatureContainer.Resolve<YourPageClassHere>() doesnt work. I got error:  BoDi.ObjectContainerException : Interface cannot be resolved